# Proper way to display image in Spring

Tags: java, image, spring

What is a the proper way to display a generated image to `<img>` tag? I tried using a different controller specifically for the img

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="../resource/img/get_chart.do" class="img-rounded" />
</div>
```

The url-mapping for the page it self is different.

But still the image doesn't show.

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/resource/img/get_chart", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void displayChart( HttpServletResponse response )
{
    response.setContentType( "image/png" );
    try
    {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart();
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG( response.getOutputStream(), chart, 700, 500 );
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/Project/resource/img/get_chart.do] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'Project'

I'm getting this.

**UPDATE:**

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Spring? Do you have a Spring controller mapped to the given URL src? If positive, can you post it?

Comment: Did you try to use absolute urls. This is less error prone.

Comment: @benjamin.d My image is generated programmatically

Comment: Your requestmapping does not match the url. You have an extra .do

Comment: Do you have any other `@RequestMapping` annotation on the class? Also, please look into your web.xml and tell me how is your Spring servlet mapped.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan I again updated my post to show the servlet mapping. And about the other mapping. The page will load through this mapping, `@RequestMapping( value = "/resource/img", method = RequestMethod.GET )`, then the image have different controller to be rendered just like I post above.

Comment: @benjamin.d Please see my servlet configuration for you to understand my URL.

Comment: Did you give a try to benjamin's answer?

Comment: @AndreiNicusan yes I did. The result is `404`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my error. The mapping that load the page where the `<img>` tag reside and src of the image shouldn't be in different class.

My mistake is that I created a separate class for the `@RequestMapping( value = "/resource/img/get_chart", method = RequestMethod.GET )`. This mapping should be also place along the controller where the first page load. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your RequestMapping is incorrect. Change it to

> /resource/img/get_chart.do

Comment: This will leave result to `http://localhost:8080/resource/img/get_chart.do`, the application name will not appear in the URL and will cause 404 error

Comment: No, not the `src` attribute should have been changed. Benjamin suggested to change the mapping in the annotation.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan I see. I tried it, but still a `404` error. I defined my servlet to have a suffix `.do` as you can see in my servlet configuration